# How do I load/get orders by period?

Tags: admin, orders, sales, reports

So I am trying to add a new column in the Orders report.

I decided to get the orders by period, so I did this `$order_id = $row->getData('period');`

Then I tried to load the orders using

```
$sales_model = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($order_id);
$subtotal = $sales_model->getSubtotal();
$items = $sales_model->getAllItems();
```

But it won't work. I tried outputting `$sales_model` and it's empty.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

From ProxiBlue (still returns nothing):

```
<?php
class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Report_Sales_Grid_Column_Renderer_Profit extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract {
    public function render(Varien_Object $row)
    {
        $fromDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($fromDate));
        $toDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($toDate));

        /* Get the collection */
        $orderCollection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('from'=>$fromDate, 'to'=>$toDate))
            ->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('eq' => Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_COMPLETE));

        return $orderCollection;

    }
}
```

Comment: with period, are you meaning from and to dates?

Comment: Yes, I need to get or load orders by that.

Answer (score 1):

Ok,

Firstly I think you are not understanding what Models and Collections are.
There is no attribute, or value called period. Not sure where you got that from.

A model as in `Mage::getModel('sales/order')` will be an object containing the relevant data of one item. Generally that is laoded directly by the entity_id of the order that you are interested in. (`->load($order_id)`)

So, considering the code you supplied in your question, what you have tried would not work, as you are wanting back a `Collection` of `Models`

So, to get a collection, you would use `Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()`, and then apply filters to that collection (in your case date ranges). You would then be able to iterate the collection, and deal with each model held in the collection in any way you want.

To answer your question:

```
$fromDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime(<YOUR START DATE>));
$toDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime(<YOUR END DATE>));

/* Get the collection */
$orderCollection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('from'=>$fromDate, 'to'=>$toDate))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('eq' => Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_COMPLETE));
```

you woudl then do something with the collection.

```
foreach ($orderCollection as $orderModel) {
       // do somehing with the Model
}
```

Hope that helps.

EDIT1:

To test the query, output the raw sql, and run it in a mysql client.

```
$select = $orderCollection->getSelect();
echo (string) $select;
```

Comment: This inside a `render` function. I added you code (see my EDIT) and it still shows nothing whenever I do a report.

Comment: Well, read the code. I did not expect you to just paste teh code, and not adjust your from and to dates accordingly. If you are just using the From and to dates as per the code, you are asking for orders from and to "1970-01-01 08:00:00"

Comment: I adjusted the answer to make it more clear for you

Comment: Hmm, it still doesn't return anything in the reports column.

Comment: are you sure yo have data resulting from your query?

Comment: See edit1: in answer

Comment: Okay, I will check this.

Comment: It outputs this query `SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `sales_flat_order` AS `main_table` WHERE (status = 'complete')` and it returns nothing.

Comment: what do you get with `SELECT main_table.* FROM sales_flat_order AS main_table`

Comment: I get the order I made.

Comment: State = processing, status = processing, entity_id = 4, etc.

Comment: Ok, so, considering the code I gave you, why do you think you are not getting any results? At this point I cannot help you further. The question asked was answered. Think a little ;)

Comment: Thanks. I tried returning this: `$orderCollection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();` but it's still empty.. I don't know why.